# Logging SFTP File Transfers in Docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, sftp

I want to log SFTP file transfers. My `sshd_conf` is:

```
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

PermitRootLogin yes

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes

UsePAM yes

AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
UseDNS no

Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -l INFO -f AUTH
```

Host keys generated like this:

```
$ ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -f ssh_host_rsa_key
$ ssh-keygen -N "" -t ed25519 -f ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

SFTP server runs in Docker container created by this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y openssh-server

RUN echo 'root:123456' | chpasswd

COPY ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
COPY ssh_host_ed25519_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN chmod 400 /etc/ssh/*

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e"]
```

And the only output I have after successful login and file uploading:

```
$ docker run --rm --name sftp-server -p "2222:22" test/sftp
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Server listening on :: port 22.
Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from 172.17.0.1 port 58556 ssh2
```

However, I would expect output as described in [OpenSSH wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting#Logging_SFTP_File_Transfers):

```
Oct 22 11:59:50 server internal-sftp[4929]: open "/home/fred/foo" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0664
Oct 22 11:59:50 server internal-sftp[4929]: close "/home/fred/foo" bytes read 0 written 928
```

What might be a problem with my setup?

Answer (score 2):

You've configured `sftp-server` to log to syslog, not stderr.  You need to rip off the `-l`/`-f` options and replace them with `-e`.

Comment: I already have the '-e' option in Dockerfile (see CMD) and note I have logging output. However, I don't see log entries for file uploading/downloading. Removing `-l/-r` options changes nothing. Do you know why?

Comment: I said `sftp-server`. and not `sshd`. for a very, very good reason.  They are separate programs with separate logging configurations.

Comment: Sorry, now I see the difference. However, adding the option `-e` doesn't add the desired output to Docker logs. Nevertheless, I enabled `rsyslog` and now I can see `sftp-server` logs into `/var/log/messages`. Thanks for the clarification between `sftp-server` and `sshd` deffrence.